# 4-layer neural network using relu activation function doesn't work well

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

I've been trying to make 4-layer neural network using relu activation function

But it doesn't work well...

I guess the problem is back propagation part.

because rest of the code works well when i was using sigmoid activation function

I only fixed back propagation part

so could you anyone teach me what's wrong with my code

Upcoming code is part of my neural network class

Additionally i don't want use any deep learning frame work Sorry..!

```
    # train the neural network
def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
    # convert inputs list to 2d array
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
    targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

    # calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
    # calculate the signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    # calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs2 = numpy.dot(self.wh1h2, hidden_outputs)
    # calculate the signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs2 = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs2)

    # calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wh2o, hidden_outputs2)
    # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

    # output layer error is the (target - actual)
    output_errors = targets - final_outputs
    # hidden layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden nodes
    hidden_errors2 = numpy.dot(self.wh2o.T, output_errors) 
    # hidden layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden nodes
    hidden_errors = numpy.dot(self.wh1h2.T, hidden_errors2)

    #Back propagation part
    # update the weights for the links between the hidden and output layers
    # self.wh2o += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)), numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs2))
    self.wh2o += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * numpy.heaviside(final_inputs,0.0) ), numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs2))

    # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
    self.wh1h2 += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_errors2 * numpy.heaviside(hidden_inputs2, 0.0) ), numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs))

    # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
    self.wih += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_errors * numpy.heaviside(hidden_inputs, 0.0) ), numpy.transpose(inputs))



    pass
```

wh2o means weight which propagte secod hidden layer to outputlayer

wh1h2 means weight which propagte first hidden layer to second layer

wih means weight which propagte input layer to hidden layer

Comment: "Doesn't work well" is not a proper description of what is wrong, you need to be precise on what is the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the specifics of your code; relu's popularity stems mostly from its success in CNN's. For small regression problems like this, its a pretty awful choice, as it really brings the vanishing gradient problem to the forefront; which for complicated reasons isnt as much of an issue in big CNN problems. There are various ways of making your architecture more robust to vanishing gradients; but not using relu would be my first suggestion (maxout is your best friend of vanishing gradients are a persistent problem). Bottom line; this may very well have nothing to do with a problem in your code, but be purely one of architecture.